# insert using LinqToSql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

```
insert into table1 (Wicket, Run, Catch) 
values (Wicket + 2, Run + 22, Catch + 5)
```

This statement is used to insert data using a stored procedure.

How can I insert data same way without using stored procedure but using LinqToSql?

What will be code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386941.aspx

```
// Create a new Order object.
Order ord = new Order
{
    OrderID = 12000,
    ShipCity = "Seattle",
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now
    // …
};

// Add the new object to the Orders collection.
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord);

// Submit the change to the database.
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Make some adjustments.
    // ...
    // Try again.
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var db = new NorthwindDataContext();
// Create a new Order object.
Order ord = new Order
{
    OrderID = 12000,
    ShipCity = "Seattle",
    OrderDate = DateTime.Now
    // …
};

// Add the new object to the Orders collection.
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord);

// Submit the change to the database.
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    // Make some adjustments.
    // ...
    // Try again.
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
using(var context = new YourContext())
{
 var table1 = new table1(){ //fill out properties };
 context.table1.InsertOnSubmit(table1);
 context.SubmitChanges();
}
```